# A problem involving a pack of $27$ distinct cards.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math, combinations

**Regional Mathematics Olympiad (India) $2019$ Leg $2$ Question $5$**

> There is a pack of $27$ distinct cards, and each card has three values on it. The first value is a shape from $\{\Delta,\square,\odot\}$; the second value is a letter from $\{A,B,C\}$; and the third value is a number from $\{1,2,3\}$.
>   In how many ways can we choose an unordered set of 3 cards from the pack, so that no two of the chosen cards have two matching values.
>   For example we can choose $\{\Delta A1,\Delta B2,\odot C3\}$
>   But we cannot choose $\{\Delta A1,\square B2,\Delta C1\}$

In [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1949803p13453695) AoPS thread, two people got $36$ as the answer but I got $1278$ (I am Festus). Also, a solution [here](https://www.allen.ac.in/pncf/rmo/pdf/phase-II/RMO-Paper-with-Solution-10-nov.pdf) matches with my answer, though my solution was different.

I can't quote my answer verbatim, but here is a gist of my solution : I said that, if we calculate number of ordered sets and divide it by $6$, we shall get number of unordered sets. Then I proceeded to calculate by brute forcing(assuming cases), and arrived at $7668$, ordered sets and thus $1278$ unordered sets. Please let me know if I am correct or not.

Edit: as pointed out by Jose Maria, I made a typo in the example provided in the question, which has now been rectified. P.S. Copy-pasted it from the AoPS link.

Comment: Clearly $36$ is too small.  For the first two cards, you can pick the first in $27$ ways, then there are $6$ prohibited cards for the second-you can choose which position to change in $3$ ways and the way to change it in $2$.  This gives $\frac 12(27 \cdot 20)=270$ pairs for the first two cards.

Comment: I was thinking that they had misinterpreted the question, thus arriving at $36$. But I wanted to be sure.

Comment: $36$ comes from requiring that there be no match in any position.  There are $27$ ways to choose the first card, then $8$ ways to choose the second card, then the third card is determined.  $27 \cdot 8/3!=36$

Comment: But the question allows one match, so the answer would be greater, right?

Comment: I think this is just a question of interpretation.  I read the question as requiring that no symbol appear more than once, in which case the answer is $36$.  But the phrasing is vague so other interpretations are possible.

Comment: @lulu I had to spend nearly $5$ minutes just trying to understand what the question was talking about.

Comment: The solution you link to is correct.

Comment: Whereas I just hastily assumed my reading was the only possible one, which it clearly isn't.  I definitely agree that the question is ambiguous.

Comment: @RossMillikan so the answer is $1278$? And my answer is correct?

Comment: You linked to an answer that says $1278$ is correct.  I agreed with it.

Comment: Your two examples are badly chosen -- in the first, no two cards have _any_ matching value; and in the second, the first and third cards have _two_ matching values. Why didn't you give us an example where two of the cards have _one_ matching value? After all, this is the crux of the problem.

Comment: @TonyK fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

36 is the solution to the problem:

> ... pack, so that no two of the chosen cards have **ANY** matching values.

Your solution of 1278 is correct for the given problem, I would assume the solutions in AOPS have misread the problem, as I did at first as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I can't comment due to reputation. The only way is to propose a solution.
Check the allowed combinations in the two problems. Are differents!!

Here (solution 36) the example is {ΔA1,□B2,⊙C3}

In the other problem (solution 1278) the example is {ΔA1,ΔB2,⊙C3}

Comment: I'm sorry, what you are saying is unclear to me.

Comment: In the problem proposed here the solution is 36. In the problem proposed with solution 1278 the example is different.

Comment: Oh. I shall check with the original question paper and update. Unfortunately, that will take some time as I'm not at home currently.

Comment: I mean that it is the solution. Are two different problems, with two different solutions.